# python, You must not use 8-bit bytestrings

Tags: python, sql, encoding, pandas

I'm converting a SQL query in python into a pandas dataframe. Then I'm using pandas sql to make a left outer join between two pandas dataframe.
My code is:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
from pandasql import sqldf
from collections import OrderedDict
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

top_name_gender = [['Nicole','female'],['Jerson','male'],['Kim','female']]

gender = OrderedDict()
gender['first_name'] = []
gender['gender'] = []

for row in top_name_gender:
    gender['first_name'].append(row[0])
    gender['gender'].append(row[1])


gender_df = DataFrame(gender)

customer = OrderedDict()
customer['email'] = []
customer['first_name'] = []
customer['gender'] = []

query_customer = """SELECT 
                    email,
                    lower(substring_index(first_name,' ',1)) as first_name,
                    gender 
                    FROM bob_live.customer 
                    limit 10000000000"""

con = mdb.connect(host='db03.phlan', port=3306, user='crm', passwd='.....', db='bob_live')
cur = con.cursor()                  
cur.execute(query_customer)
for row in cur.fetchall():
        customer['email'].append(row[0])
        customer['first_name'].append(row[1])
        customer['gender'].append(row[2])

customer_df = DataFrame(customer)

query1 = """"
                    select customer_df.*, gender_df.*
                    from customer_df
                    left outter join gender_df
                    on customer_df.first_name = gender_df.first_name"""

joined = sqldf(query1,locals())
joined.text_factory = str
```

But I have this following error:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless
>   you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like
>   text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just
>   switch your application to Unicode strings

I tried to add

```
con.text_factory = str
cur.text_factory = str
```

But it doesn't change anything.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Do you paste exact code, that you have? In that case, you have odd symbol '"' here: `query1 = """"`

Comment: Try to do this: `joined.text_factory = unicode` or this: `query1 = u"""...`

Comment: thanks for your comment @stalk, I tried both but it's not working

Comment: The fact that you read it from a sql database does not matter here (by the way, this is easier if you use `pd.read_sql_query` for that), so you can leave that out. Can you instead give also a reproducible example of `customer_df` that gives the error?

Comment: hi @joris thanks for your answer and your advice (I'm now using read_sql_query), well customer_df doesn't give me any error

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm getting the exact same problem using pysqldf

Answer (score 3):

Turns out my problem was with the text in the dataframes that I was trying to merge. It sufficed to specify the proper encoding when calling read_csv: for example `encoding='latin-1'`

Comment: For the record - this solved my problem in pandas 0.17.1